# multi-vendor ecommerce system with multi language prefered products

Tags: wordpress, magento, joomla, e-commerce, prestashop

I just want to start an online marketplace with many vendors on it. There are few systems that support that like IXXO, Wordpress (dokan) etc... but I want to have a shop with multi-language function and not only the language changes, also the products. So you got one system for all countries but there are only the products from the actually chosen language displayed.

Does anyone know of a eCommerce system that comes close to these requirements?

Answer (score 1):

I think Magento is best for you because it fulfills all of your requirement.And there are many extensions that help you to fulfill your need easily.

Answer (score 0):

WordPress (Dokan) Support multi-language.